# Animation of UILabel's frame (and other views' frames) in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, quartz-core

Please help. Trying to get animation of frame position working inside a UITableViewCell, specifically I'm trying to move the default UILabel (cell.textLabel). However, no matter what technique I use, I can't get any view inside the cell to move. The animation of colour and alpha works as outlined by the code below.

Cheers in advance for help.

Andy

Here is the code I am using:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0) {

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        CGRect textLabelFrame = cell.textLabel.frame;
        textLabelFrame.origin.x = -textLabelFrame.size.width;

       [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
            delay:0.0
            options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
            animations:^{
                cell.textLabel.frame = textLabelFrame; // THIS DOESN'T WORK - HELP!
                cell.imageView.frame = CGRectOffset(cell.imageView.frame,0,0); // EVEN TRYING TO MOVE IMAGEVIEW DOESN'T WORK
                cell.textLabel.alpha = 0; // This animates
                cell.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; // This animates
            }
            completion:^(BOOL finished){
                NSLog(@"Done!");
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to create custom uitableview cell and use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to reposition the default label or image view in a standard cell. If you want to do that, you should add your own subviews to the cell's contentView, and do your animations with those.